# Async function not waiting for returned data to dispatch action to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

My program is dispatching two actions to my reducer when it should only be dispatching one. I'm using an async function but I don't think it's working properly.

My console log prints this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const pid = params.get("pid");
        console.log(pid);

        async function fetchData() {
          const docRef = db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(user?.uid)
            .collection("products")
            .doc(`${pid}`);

          const data = await docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
            setName(doc.data().name);
            setPrice(doc.data().price);
            setDescription(doc.data().description);
            setQuantity(doc.data().quantity);
            setDownloaded(true);

            dispatch({
              type: "SET_EDIT_PRODUCTS",
              item: {
                name: name,
              },
            });
          });
        }
        fetchData();
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  },);
```

Comment: probably you also want to check for truthy name. `if (user && name) {`

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency for your useEffect, this means that whenever the `name` variable changes the effect hook is triggered. In your console data it seems that first the name variable is an empty string, then it has a value.

Comment: Hi Paula, I removed the dependancy and it renders the the ```pid``` 4 times now

Comment: Are you using with an empty dependency array? `useEffect(() => { ... }, [] )`. If you use an empty dependency array, the function runs only once, when component is mounted, with no dependency array it runs on every component render.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` runs 2 times. First when the component is mounted, and 2nd time when the `name` dependency is changed.

To avoid dispatching the action on mount with empty `name` you need to check for truthy `name`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (user && name) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const pid = params.get("pid");
        console.log(pid);

        async function fetchData() {
          const docRef = db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(user?.uid)
            .collection("products")
            .doc(`${pid}`);

          const data = await docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
            setName(doc.data().name);
            setPrice(doc.data().price);
            setDescription(doc.data().description);
            setQuantity(doc.data().quantity);
            setDownloaded(true);

            dispatch({
              type: "SET_EDIT_PRODUCTS",
              item: {
                name: name,
              },
            });
          });
        }
        fetchData();
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  }, [name]);
```

Comment: I want to query the database on mount and then set the name, price, description, and downloaded state variables the first time the useEffect runs. Currenty, the first time it runs, these variables are empty but are set the second time the useEffect runs.